extendability of fibre bundles on manifolds with same dimensions
Let $M$ be an $m$-manifold. Let $M'\subseteq  M$, where
$M'$ is also an $m$-manifold.
Let $N$ be an $n$-manifold. Let $N'\subseteq  N$, where
$N'$ is also an $n$-manifold.
Suppose there is  fibre bundle  $\xi':  N'\longrightarrow  E'\longrightarrow  M'$.
Question. Could we impose any  conditions  on  $M$, $M'$,   $N$,  $N'$  and  $\xi'$  such  that  there  exists  a  fibre  bundle
$\xi:  N\longrightarrow  E\longrightarrow  M$
satisfying   $\xi'$  is  a  sub-bundle  of  $\xi\mid_{M'}$,  where  $\xi\mid_{M'}$  is   the  restriction  of  $\xi$  to  $M'$?
Are  there  any  references?  Thanks.

You can formulate this problem in terms of classifying maps and obstruction theory. Have you thought about this problem in this direction?
